# Bug with @XmlAnyAttribute and methods? (using JAXB RI)

Tags: java, jaxb

I have a problem with my JAXB. I have a method with @XmlAnyAttribute (on my getter) but it doesn't seem to work with the setter (using JAXB RI if it matters).

Simplified code:

```
@XmlRootElement( name = "element" )
@XmlAccessorType( value = XmlAccessType.PUBLIC_MEMBER )
public class Element
{
    private Map<QName, String> convertedAttributes = new HashMap<QName, String>();

    private List<Attribute> attributes = new ArrayList<Attribute>();

    @XmlAnyAttribute
    public Map<QName, String> getConvertedAttributes() throws Exception
    {
        if ( attributes != null )
        {
            return new AttributeMapAdapter().marshal( attributes );
        }

        return new HashMap<QName, String>();
    }

    public void setConvertedAttributes( Map<QName, String> convertedAttributes )
    {
        this.convertedAttributes = convertedAttributes;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public List<Attribute> getAttributes()
    {
        return attributes;
    }

    public void setAttributes( List<Attribute> attributes )
    {
        this.attributes = attributes;
    }
}
```

This work great for marshalling, and I get the output I want. But when I try to unmarshall it, no values it sent to the setter.

I tried moving the @XmlAnyAttribute annotation to the field, and it works fine (but then I can't do the adaption in the getter).

It kinda feels like a bug, but I'm not sure. Any ideas? I'm using Java 1.6 on Mac OS X (10.7.2)

Comment: I can provide more code if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a bug in the JAXB RI.  The problem is in your `getConvertedAttributes()` method.   The following works a bit better:

```
public Map<QName, String> getConvertedAttributes() throws Exception
{
    if(!convertedAttributes.isEmpty()) {
        return convertedAttributes;
    }
    if ( attributes != null ) {
        convertedAttributes = new AttributeMapAdapter().marshal( attributes ); 
    } else {
        convertedAttributes = new HashMap<QName, String>();
    }
    return convertedAttributes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your setter has to unmarshall the map again. So you need an adapter for the other direction, too.

Comment: I have a mapper for that direction. But convertedAttributes is always empty, it doesn't get any values. Using @XmlAnyAttribute on the field gives me values to unmarshall, but using it on the method does not work.

Comment: @mortenoh yeah you're right, it will use only the getter to get access to the underlying map. You will have to decorate the returned map of the getter and intercept the put and get methods of there. I would suggest to make your current adapter implementing the map interface and returning it.